# Remote access to notebook is very slow

Tags: notebooks, remote-access

I am using *Mathematica* at work remotely from a computer in my building and I can edit notebooks by opening them from terminal via ssh without problem (a little slow if there is a figure with many points, but that's all).

Now I need to work from home, but editing a notebook that I open from terminal is just impossible because it is too slow and freezes each time I click on it. I am still using ssh on Ubuntu 12.04.

Any idea how I can make it faster?

Comment: This doesn't sound like a Mathematica problem.  This sounds more like a internet/network latency problem.  Have you tested the connection by trying to use any other application (maybe a word processor).  I suspect that you'll have the same trouble.

Comment: Why do you use notebooks at all? I usually use the terminal "frontend" when logged on to a remote computer by ssh. So just log in by ssh and type math instead of mathematica. This works and is fast over nearly every kind of connection.

Comment: @RolfMertig But then you don't have a notebook, no?

Comment: @M.R. No. But maybe this was just a matter of the wrong desktops settings in Ubuntu ( or the wrong Linux distro. I used CentOS and Debian and there are no problems unless you use fancy window managers).